# How to get Image specific image in geckofx web browser control

Tags: vb.net, geckofx

I am using web browser control in my another application. and i am try to copy image using following code its work fine.

```
   Dim doc As IHTMLDocument2 = _
      DirectCast(webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, IHTMLDocument2)

   Dim imgRange As IHTMLControlRange = _
      DirectCast(DirectCast(doc.body, _
      HTMLBody).createControlRange(), IHTMLControlRange)

   For Each img As IHTMLImgElement In doc.images
    imgRange.add(DirectCast(img, IHTMLControlElement))

    imgRange.execCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)

    Using bmp As Bitmap = DirectCast( _
        Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), Bitmap)
        bmp.Save("C:\" + img.nameProp)
    End Using
   Next
```

but now i use GeckoFX Web browser control in my application. so any can help how to get image Using GeckoFX web browser control.